# AFNetworking 2 How to stop caching?

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking-2

I am tearing my hair out. The following code refuses to overwrite the previously downloaded file. Any ideas?

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
configuration.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;


AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];


NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL
                                         cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                     timeoutInterval:60.0];

NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {

    NSURL *documentsDirectoryPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject]];
    return [documentsDirectoryPath URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);
    NSLog(@"error %@", error );
       NSLog(@"response %@", response );

}];
[downloadTask resume];
```

Comment: Try removing the file at the destination path

Comment: I was hoping to avoid solving the problem in this way as it just seems messy and not how AFNetworking (I can only assume) was mean't to be used. Though I appreciate your input.

Comment: In my experience, this is how NSURLSession works, and AFNetworking just wraps this behaviour.

Comment: OK, I think I'm in agreement now. I just have to accept this is how it is! Thanks David.

Comment: I'll add this is an answer if you're happy to accept it. Hopefully it'll help others.

Answer (score 2):

Use the ephemeral session configuration instead:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration];
```